# How to execute a command in a deployed Azure Docker Windows Container Instance

Tags: azure, docker, containers

I've spent days researching this but can find no examples of how to do this, and the documentation for Azure.ResoureManager provides little insight. Given a running container instance (deployed Docker Windows container) and the latest Azure SDK for .NET (Azure.ResourceManager...), how does one execute a command in the running container? The command would be in the form of "c:\folder\dothis.exe blobURL".

Although deprecated, I have tried unsuccessfully to use the Microsoft.Azure.Management Fluent libraries as shown in the code below, which, by the way, does not work! Maybe it works on a Linux container, but not on a Windows container. See code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent.Models;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string resourceGroupName = "HContainerGroup";
        string containerGroupName = "hcontainer";
        //string containerImage = "hcontaineregistry.azurecr.io/horoscope-container-img:v5";
        // Set the AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION environment variable with the full
        // path to an auth file. Create an auth file with the Azure CLI:
        // az ad sp create-for-rbac --sdk-auth > my.azureauth
        string authFilePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
        // Authenticate(RestClient restClient, string tenantId)
        // Authenticate with Azure
        ISubscription sub;
        IAzure azure = Azure.Authenticate(authFilePath).WithDefaultSubscription(); //.WithSubscription("e94537de-4c00-4abc-8df3-0ec30cbdf3a8"); //.WithDefaultSubscription();
        sub = azure.GetCurrentSubscription();

        IResourceGroup resGroup = azure.ResourceGroups.GetByName(resourceGroupName);
        Region azureRegion = resGroup.Region;
        Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent.IContainerGroup containerGroup = azure.ContainerGroups.GetByResourceGroup(resourceGroupName, "hcontainer");
        // This all works fine up to here. containerGroup has all the right stuff, so the ExecuteCommand function below should work great !!!!!!!!!!!
        string command = @"c:\GetHCmdLine\GetHCmdLine.exe testblob1";
        IContainerExecResponse containerExecResponse = containerGroup.ExecuteCommand("hcontainer", command, 120, 120); // !!! Does not work !!!
        string log = containerGroup.GetLogContent("hcontainer", 2);
    }
}
```

NOTE that I can use Azure CLI and the following command to successfully execute the command in the container:

```
az container exec -g HContainerGroup --name hcontainer --exec-command "c:\GetHCmdLine\GetHCmdLine.exe testblob1"
```

I have tried to use the new Azure.ResourceManager packages that replace the Fluent stuff to try to send a command to the running container, but I can't figure out how to use them.

Comment: Have you tried? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-exec

Comment: Yes, but I need to do it in C# with .NET. See the revised question above.

Answer (score 1):

From C#, you can make a REST call to the Azure API.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/demo/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/demo1/containers/container1/exec?api-version=2022-09-01

{
  "command": "/bin/bash",
  "terminalSize": {
    "rows": 12,
    "cols": 12
  }
}
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/containers/execute-command?tabs=HTTP

Comment: Thanks, Sharp. Yes, I've seen that but have not tried it because you can do exactly the same thing with the Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent .NET libs, which I could not get to work either. I'll give it a try and, if it works, I'll come back mark it as the Answer.